# gzuncompress, gzinflate, gzdecode in java

Tags: java, php

I've been looking to unzip strings of data in JAVA that were compressed in PHP with gzcompress, gzdeflate and gzencode.

For example, the result of running gzcompress `("Hello!")` is `x��H���W�`, The result of running gzdeflate `("Hello!")` is `�H���W` and the result of running gzencode `("Hello!")` is      `��H���WV�*�`.

I want to decompress the result in java.

But I have some errors, for example, if I try to unzip a string that was compressed with PHP's gzencode in Java, I get the following exception: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format, this is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws DataFormatException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    String textGzencode = "��H���WV�*�";

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(textGzencode.getBytes());
    GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

    String readed;

    while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(readed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so have you looked at the `Deflater*Stream`, `Inflater*Stream` and `GZip*Stream` classes?

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed some of these classes, but I get errors like: java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check, Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format

Comment: Well that would suggest it's not actually in GZIP format. But aside from anything else, the code you've provided starts with a *string* and converts it into bytes. *Compressed data should never be represented as text like that*. If you really need a text representation, use base64... but basically, you should be reading it in from a `FileInputStream` or similar. This is *binary* data, not text. (Just because some programming languages don't distinguish clearly between those doesn't make it any less important.)

Comment: Exactly, it's strange because in the PHP documentation it says: Create a string compressed with gzip... Yes, I need a text representation but if I use base64 the string size would increase by about 33% in general, my goal is to reduce considerably the size of the string in PHP and get the original string in Java.

Comment: "Yes, I need a text representation" - why? This *isn't text*. It isn't a string. The sooner you accept that, the better. You're transferring *binary data*.